# Name look-up fails - c++ namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

Could you explain why namespace look-up fails in that code?

```
namespace B {
namespace C {
   int i;
}
}
namespace A {
namespace B {

void foo() {
    // why does not much A::B::C
    B::C::i = 3;   
}
}
}
```

Yes, I know ::B::C::i works because we indicates global namespace but I am curious why look-up does not search outside B::C namespaces when we don't use :: before B.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no `A::B::C`. It looked for `B`, it found `A::B`, but `A::B` has no `C`. Why would it look for *another* `B` somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the namespace `::A::B`, the unqualified lookup for `B` finds the namespace `::A::B` rather than finding the namespace `::B`. And there is no name `::A::B::C`, so the qualified lookup for `C` within the found `::A::B` fails.